# change the position of div tag dyanmically with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have an ASP button in a `div` to the right side of a page. I want to change the position to the left in the same row dynamically with `onchange` event of a dropdown.

I did this way:

```
document.getElementById('divButtonGo').style.Paddingleft="80px"
```

How do I do this with Javascript?

Comment: Side note: What are you trying to do with those `i` tags?  Are they part of your source code?  A: They're not closed anywhere; B: JavaScript doesn't go in the DOM directly like that.  It needs to be in a `script` tag.

Comment: **@david** I think the `<i>` tags were an attempt to differentiate his code from the body of the question. I would assume they can be edited out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have provided **already is** javascript. If you want to change what triggers the code to run, change where you place it.

from an `onchange` event, into a `function` in a script tag that is called by something else.

example

```
<input type="button" onclick="movediv()" />
<script>
    function movediv(){
        document.getElementById('divButtonGo').style.Paddingleft="80px"
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several things wrong here. In order of increasing importance:

1. You're missing the closing slash from your `i` tag.
2. I don't see a "divButtonGo" in your html. If it's not there at all, obviously it won't work. If it is, include it in your code snippet.
3. I'm pretty sure to set the style you're going to need `elem.style.paddingLeft`, not `elem.style.Paddingleft`
4. Your script isn't wrapped inside `<script>` tags. All Javascript has to be wrapped in these tags, *and*, in order for that code to operate sucessfully, it's going to have to be placed *after* the "divButtonGo", *or* you'll have to wire up an onload event, like `window.onload = function() { /* Bombs away! */ };`

Your final result should look something like...

```
<div id="divButtonGo">
My Awesome Content
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById("divButtonGo");
el.style.paddingLeft = "30px";
</script>
```

Also, to note, padding wont' exactly change the position of the `div`, only the position of the content inside. If you want to change the position of the `div`, use `margin-left` (in JS, `element.style.marginLeft`, i believe)

### EDIT:

I forgot you wanted it in the onchange event of a dropdown; so you'd do somethign like:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("MyDropDown");
dropdown.onchange = function() {
var el = document.getElementById("divButtonGo");
el.style.paddingLeft = "30px";
};
```